# Getting scaled dimensions in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, mobile

I'm developing a mobile app using Phonegap on Android (testing using a 720x1280 screen with the emulator). Printing screen.width and screen.height in javascript says 720x1280 which is what it should be. However, when I inspect the body in Weinre, it will say the dimensions are 360x451. The body is already annotated with width: 100%; height: 100%. I'm trying to scale certain elements to take up more space on 16x9 displays. Is there a way of getting the DPI in javascript?

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the trick is to use window.innerHeight instead of screen.height